# ADX Portal:The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present. In ADX Customer portal when displaying Entity List

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-online, adxstudio-portals

I have setup ADX Master portal in my local and connecting to Dynamics CRM 365 free subscription.

Problem I am currently facing is am not able to show the list of contacts or any other entities in ADX portals.

I have created an Entity List for Active Contacts,and created a webpage under content as "activecontacts" with Page Template as "Full Page".

When I am trying to browse to the page

`http://localhost/MasterPortal/content/activecontacts`

it is displaying a Table with header containing all columns from the selected view but not the data.

In place of data it is displaying:

`The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present`

I have verified the cookies and the hidden field (__RequestVerificationToken) on the form. This field is present on the form. Still the page is not displaying any contacts.

Please help me to solve this issue which enable me to continue my learning in ADX.

Comment: Hi Anand,
Just a query. ADX portals are still available for trial purpose for 1 month ?
Can we host this adx solution to azure can run the web portal integrated with CRM365 as trial ?
Somewhere I heard that trial is no more for ADX.

Comment: @ACRM MS aquired AdXstudio & named it as CRM portal solutions -
 which is available under Dynamics CRM 365 admin page to install it..

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem, just in case someone else runs into this.

If you upgrade adx studio from a previous version, make sure you update the entity-*.js files.  Get them from the sample project of your ADX studio new installation.  For my project, I upgrade from version 7.0.0.21 to 7.0.0.24.  Hope this helps someone else....

PS: Make sure you added the below in your Default.master page.

```
<div id="antiforgerytoken"
    data-url="<%: Url.Action("GetAntiForgeryToken", "Layout",new { area = "Portal" } ) %>"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue happen to me, to fix it I only had to run VS with elevated privileges